# bootstrap - right div eats left div?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have 2 mainly divs left 25% width and right 75%, when i rezise the browser window my right div basicly eats my left div like this http://postimg.org/image/xndfdi1pf/ and sometimes  do this http://postimg.org/image/s1wiq2tgt/ i dont know why ... anyone ?

this is media code when max width is 767px

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    ul.timeline:before {
        left: 40px;
    }

    ul.timeline > li {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      position: relative;
      width:100%;
      float: left;
      clear: left;
    }
    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        width: calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px);
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
        left: 28px;
        margin-left: 0;
        top: 16px;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        float: right;
    }

        ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 15px;
            left: -15px;
            right: auto;
        }

        ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 14px;
            left: -14px;
            right: auto;
        }

.timeline > li.timeline-inverted{
  float: left; 
  clear: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-badge{
  left: 28px;
}
}
```

the 2 divs code

```
 .cont_user{
padding-left: 80px;
width:25%;
margin-top:120px;
}

 .cont_time{
width:75%;
margin-top:20px;
}
```

if u need more code tell me pls :) ty

Comment: Can you post a fiddle/bootply?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/ -- or http://www.bootply.com/new or JSBin -- use the latest library

Comment: what code you want in fiddle/bootply ?

Comment: i get my timeline code there : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/timeline-21-with-images-and-responsive

Comment: so any idea about what i do ?